# Prestashop API Búsqueda de Productos

Tags: api, prestashop

Como podría leer un producto del Prestashop usando la API, cuando en la referencia del producto hay un simbolo & ó # por ejemplo

Ejemplo de URL que uso desde visual studio C#
https://miweb.com/api/products/?display=full&filter[reference]=[ART#]&ws_key=2VTEPWKYHW3EN7AQTQQDYTXDKXL6DMHV

https://miweb.com/api/products/?display=full&filter[reference]=[ART&]&ws_key=2VTEPWKYHW3EN7AQTQQDYTXDKXL6DMHV

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya ví la solución.
la solución es la de hacer URLENCODE.
en este caso en mí código he añadido

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(.....
```

Comment: Si está es la solución no olvides marcarla como aceptada